# Python 3 : How to convert <class 'bytes'> to <type 'str'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, type-conversion, byte

I would like to convert this  : b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x1b!!\x9c'

to this                          :  '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x1b!!\x9c'

There is an easy way?
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x1b!!\x9c'.decode() creates an error
***builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string). This is, by the way, the first result of googling "python byte to string"...

Comment: Unfortunatly, this is not answering my question.

Comment: It does answer your question, but the encoding you want is probably `.decode('iso8859')`, not `.decode('utf-8')`. If the data is supposed to be a string then you should check what encoding is used by whereever the data comes from.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack -- but it works:

```
str data = str(data)
data = data[2:]
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried and it gives me an error...   builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Try again with `utf-16`

Comment: @stef9999 if you already tried, why don't you mention it (with the error you get) in your question ???

Comment: It's better but not exactly what I need...  '\uffff\uffff\uffffᬀ'

Comment: Keep playing with the `encoding` until you get what you need

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Comment: bruno desthuilliers Sorry,  I'm new here and I didn't think about saying what I tried...  In fact, I tried almost everything I can imagine... :-)

Comment: You changed the contents of the `bytes` object! This gives an error on the OP's input.

Comment: I found it...   
1) convert data to str                      data = str(data)
2) remove the 2 first characters      data = data[2:]